# Cumulative frequency by factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have to find out the cumulative frequency, converted to percentage, of a continuous variable by factor.
For example:

```
data <- data.frame(n = sample(1:12),
                d = seq(10, 120, by = 10),
                Site = rep(c("FirstSite", "SecondSite"), 6), 
                Plot = rep(c("Plot1", "Plot1", "Plot2", "Plot2"), 3)
                )

data <- with(data, data[order(Site,Plot),])
data <- transform(data, G = ((pi * (d/2)^2) * n) / 10000)

data
    n   d       Site  Plot           G
1   7  10  FirstSite Plot1  0.05497787
5   9  50  FirstSite Plot1  1.76714587
9  12  90  FirstSite Plot1  7.63407015
3  10  30  FirstSite Plot2  0.70685835
7   5  70  FirstSite Plot2  1.92422550
11  1 110  FirstSite Plot2  0.95033178
2   3  20 SecondSite Plot1  0.09424778
6   8  60 SecondSite Plot1  2.26194671
10  6 100 SecondSite Plot1  4.71238898
4   4  40 SecondSite Plot2  0.50265482
8   2  80 SecondSite Plot2  1.00530965
12 11 120 SecondSite Plot2 12.44070691
```

I need the cumulaive frequency of column `G` by factors `Plot~Site`in order to plot a geom_step ggplot of `G` against `d` for each plot and site.
I have achieved to compute cumulative sum of `G` by factor by:

```
data.ss <- by(data[, "G"], data[,c("Plot", "Site")], function(x) cumsum(x))
# Gtot
(data.ss.tot <- sapply(ss, max))
[1]  9.456194  3.581416  7.068583 13.948671
```

Now I need to express each `Plot` `G` in the range [0..1] where 1 is `G`tot for each `Plot`.  I imagine I should divide `G` by its `Plot` `Gtot`, then apply a new `cumsum` to it. How to do it?
Please note that I have to plot this cumulative frequency against `d` not `G` itself, so it is not a proper ecdf.
Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually use `ddply` and `transform` to do this type of thing:

```
> data = ddply(data, c('Site', 'Plot'), transform, Gsum=cumsum(G), Gtot=sum(G))
> qplot(x=d, y=Gsum/Gtot, facets=Plot~Site, geom='step', data=data)
```

[image]